# Itemize inside Textblock inside Column

Tags: beamer, itemize, columns

So this is the first time I'm using Beamer and I'd like to show the image first, than the first text, then the second one ... etc
After many attempts, this is the best result I can get. The problem is that the second text is showing first then the first. as shown in the following picture. How can I fix that ?

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}

\usetheme[sectionpage=none, progressbar=frametitle, numbering=fraction]{metropolis}

\setbeamercolor{itemize item}{fg=white}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Modélisation du système}
\begin{columns}
\onslide<2->{
\column{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{textblock*}{60mm}(10mm,15mm)
\begin{itemize}
\item text 1 
\pause 
\item text 2
\end{itemize}
\end{textblock*}}
\onslide<1->{
\column{0.5\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
}
\end{columns}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: My bad,  will edit that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work:

```latex
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
\setbeamercolor{itemize item}{fg=white}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Modélisation du système}
\begin{columns}
\column{0.5\textwidth}

\begin{textblock*}{60mm}(10mm,15mm)
\pause
\begin{itemize}
\item<2-> text 1 
\item<3-> text 2
\end{itemize}
\end{textblock*}

\column{0.5\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
\end{columns}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image: image first]

Comment: Can I show the image first without any text ?

Comment: @Hibou, yes, see my edit.